# Inverse Fourier Transform of $e^{i\mathbf{k}\cdot\mathbf{R}}$ in Brillouin Zone in Proving Orthogonality of Wannier Functions

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, condensed-matter, solid-state-physics, fourier-transform

The relationship between wannier function and Bloch function like this：
$$
|\mathbf{R}_n\rangle = \dfrac{V}{(2\pi)^3}  \int_{\mathrm{BZ}} |\psi_{n\mathbf{k}}\rangle e^{-i\mathbf{k}\cdot \mathbf{R}}d\mathbf{k} \tag{1}
$$
where $V$ represents the volume of primitive cells in the lattice;

Others have proved $\langle \mathbf{R}_n|\mathbf{R}_m'\rangle = \delta_{nm}\delta_{\mathbf{R}\mathbf{R}'}$ [Maximally localized Wannier functions](https://journals.aps.org/rmp/abstract/10.1103/RevModPhys.84.1419). I try to prove this formula.
$$
\begin{align}
\langle\mathbf{R}_n|\mathbf{R}_m'\rangle =& \bigg{(} \dfrac{V}{(2\pi)^3}  \int_{\mathrm{BZ}} \langle\psi_{n\mathbf{k}}|e^{i\mathbf{k}\cdot \mathbf{R}} d\mathbf{k}  \bigg{)}\bigg{(} \dfrac{V}{(2\pi)^3}  \int_{\mathrm{BZ}} |\psi_{m\mathbf{k}}\rangle e^{-i\mathbf{k}\cdot \mathbf{R}'} d\mathbf{k}  \bigg{)} \\
=&\bigg{(} \dfrac{V}{(2\pi)^3} \bigg{)}^2 \int_{\mathrm{BZ} } \langle\psi_{n\mathbf{k}}|\psi_{m\mathbf{k}}\rangle e^{i\mathbf{k}\cdot \mathbf{R} }e^{-i\mathbf{k}\cdot \mathbf{R}'} d\mathbf{k} \\
=&\bigg{(} \dfrac{V}{(2\pi)^3} \bigg{)}^2 \int_{\mathrm{BZ} } \dfrac{(2\pi)^3}{V} \delta_{nm}e^{i\mathbf{k}\cdot (\mathbf{R} - \mathbf{R}') }  d\mathbf{k} \\
=&\dfrac{V}{(2\pi)^3} \delta_{nm} \int_{\mathrm{BZ} }e^{i\mathbf{k}\cdot (\mathbf{R} - \mathbf{R}') }  d\mathbf{k} \tag{2}  
\end{align}
$$
Inverse from the results Ican get:
$$
\int_{\mathrm{BZ} }e^{i\mathbf{k}\cdot (\mathbf{R} - \mathbf{R}') }  d\mathbf{k} = \dfrac{(2\pi)^3}{V} \delta_{\mathbf{R}\mathbf{R}'} \tag{3}
$$

But I can't prove that eq(3) holds：
$$
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{i\mathbf{k}\cdot (\mathbf{R} - \mathbf{R}') }  d\mathbf{k} = (2\pi)^3\delta_{\mathbf{R}\mathbf{R}'} \tag{4}
$$
How to derive eq(3) from eq(4)?

Comment: @JasonFunderberker Thank you

Comment: Have you tried proving $(3)$ by explicit computation?

Comment: @JasonFunderberker I haven't tried it, and since the reduce wave vector k is limited to the Brillouin zone, I think the result of integration in the Brillouin zone and infinite integration is the same, both $(2\pi)^3\delta_{RR'}$

Comment: The units on both sides of your last equation don't match. The LHS has units of $k$-volume, while the RHS has no units. I've deleted my previous comment for various reasons, but no, this is not what I meant to say.

Comment: @JasonFunderberker Yes, I didn't notice this problem before, I'll deduce it again, thank you

Comment: I don't understand why you want to derive $(3)$ from $(4)$ (which I think is wrong). Most books I know dealing with lattice sums and or Fourier transforms in solid state etc. in a good manner are in German (but I don't know many solid state books); but there are for sure books in other languages containing detailed derivations. For example, in *Principles of condensed matter physics. Chaikin & Lubensky* there is some discussion regarding these topics. Maybe A&M has some good discussion, too. I don't know by heart. In any case, you might consider to ask this question on matter modeling SE.

Comment: Yes, (4) is seemingly wrong. The delta function in (4) should be a Dirac delta function not a Kronecker delta function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note: Sorry, I misread your question before I wrote this. Your manipulations are fine, but the derivation I give here might be helpful to others, so I'll leave it.

---

$$\langle \mathbf R_n,\mathbf R'_m\rangle = \int \mathrm d^3r \left(\frac{V}{(2\pi)^3}\int_{BZ} \mathrm d^3k \ e^{-i\mathbf k \cdot (\mathbf r-\mathbf R)} \overline{u_{n\mathbf k}(\mathbf r)}\right)\left(\frac{V}{(2\pi)^3}\int_{BZ} \mathrm d^3k'\ e^{i \mathbf k'\cdot (\mathbf r-\mathbf R')}u_{m\mathbf k'}(\mathbf r)\right)$$
$$= \frac{V^2}{(2\pi)^6} \int d^3r \int_{BZ} d^3k\int_{BZ} d^3k' \ e^{-i(\mathbf k-\mathbf k')\cdot \mathbf r} e^{i(\mathbf k\cdot \mathbf R-\mathbf k'\cdot \mathbf R')}\overline{u_{n\mathbf k}(\mathbf r)} u_{m\mathbf k'}(\mathbf r)$$

We can separate the integral over $\mathbf r$ first:
$$\int \mathrm d^3r \ e^{-i(\mathbf k-\mathbf k')\cdot \mathbf r} \overline{u_{n\mathbf k}(\mathbf r)} u_{m\mathbf k'}(\mathbf r) = \sum_{\mathscr R} e^{-i(\mathbf k-\mathbf k')\cdot \mathscr R} \int_{u.c} e^{-i(\mathbf k-\mathbf k')\cdot \mathbf r}\overline{u_{n\mathbf k}(\mathbf r)}u_{m\mathbf k'}(\mathbf r)$$
where the sum over $\mathscr R$ is over all of the lattice sites, and $u.c.$ refers to the unit cell.  The sum evaluates to $\frac{(2\pi)^3}{V_0} \delta(\mathbf k-\mathbf k')$ where $V_0$ is the volume of the unit cell. Because of the $\delta$-function (which will fire when we perform the $\mathbf k'$ integral), this becomes
$$\frac{(2\pi)^3}{V} \delta(\mathbf k-\mathbf k') \int_{u.c.}\mathrm d^3r\  \overline{u_{n\mathbf k}(\mathbf r)u_{m\mathbf k}(\mathbf r)}= \frac{(2\pi)^3}{V} \delta(\mathbf k-\mathbf k') \delta_{nm}$$
where we've used that $u_{n\mathbf k}$ and $u_{m\mathbf k}$ are orthonormal.  Plugging this back in to the original expression and evaluating the $\mathbf k'$ integral yields
$$\langle \mathbf R_n,\mathbf R'_m\rangle = \frac{V}{(2\pi)^3}\delta_{nm}\int_{BZ} \mathrm d^3k\ e^{i\mathbf k \cdot (\mathbf R-\mathbf R')}$$

Finally,
$$\int_{BZ} d^3\mathbf k \ e^{i\mathbf k\cdot (\mathbf R-\mathbf R')} = \frac{(2\pi)^3}{V} \delta_{\mathbf R,\mathbf R'}$$
which yields the result you're looking for.

---

> But I can't prove that [the following equation] holds:
> $$
> \int_{\mathrm{BZ} }e^{i\mathbf{k}\cdot (\mathbf{R} - \mathbf{R}') }  d\mathbf{k} = \dfrac{(2\pi)^3}{V} \delta_{\mathbf{R}\mathbf{R}'} \tag{3}
> $$

Consider the 1D problem for simplicity. Let the lattice vector be $\mathbf a$ with magnitude $|\mathbf a|=a$.  Then we have

$$\int_{-\pi/a}^{\pi/a} \mathrm dk e^{ik(na)}=\begin{cases}\frac{e^{in\pi}-e^{-in\pi}}{na} = 0& n\neq 0 \\ \frac{2\pi}{a} & n=0\end{cases}$$

The 3D version is a fairly straightforward generalization of this. Let $\mathbf R = \sum_i n_i \mathbf a_i$ where the $\mathbf a_i$'s are the lattice vectors. Since the integration region $BZ$ is generically not rectangular, it is convenient to define
$$\mathbf k \equiv \pmatrix{k_1\\k_2\\k_3} = [\mathbf b_1 \mathbf b_2 \mathbf b_3] \pmatrix{\lambda_1 \\\lambda_2 \\ \lambda_3}$$
where $[\mathbf b_1 \mathbf b_2 \mathbf b_3]$ is the $3\times 3$ matrix whose columns $\mathbf b_i$ are the reciprocal lattice vectors, and $\lambda_i \in [-1/2,1/2]$.  Switching integration variables to $\lambda_i$ brings in a factor of $\mathrm{det}([\mathbf b_1 \mathbf b_2 \mathbf b_3]) = \frac{(2\pi)^3}{V}$ (the volume of the BZ), and our integral becomes
$$\frac{(2\pi)^3}{V}\int_{-1/2}^{1/2} \mathrm d\lambda_1 \int_{-1/2}^{1/2} \mathrm d\lambda_2 \int_{-1/2}^{1/2} \mathrm d\lambda_3 \ e^{2\pi i(n \lambda_1 + m \lambda_2 + \ell \lambda_3)}$$
where we've used that $\mathbf b_i \cdot \mathbf a_j = 2\pi \delta_{ij}$.  From there, the integral decouples into three copies of the aforementioned 1D integral, with the end result giving $\frac{(2\pi)^3}{V}$ if $n=m=\ell=0$ and $0$ otherwise.